# Azure Database Connection with Android Studio

Tags: java, android, database, azure

I am working on an android studio project and I developed a database connection with Azure from android studio(Java). But the thing is, this connection gets established successfully on some internet networks and on some networks connection establishment is unsuccessful like in this case android studio gives error "Communications link failure The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server". While I have set the firewall of Azure database to global i.e Ip addresses range is set from 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255 on firewall .I don't know what's really going on because on changing network the only thing that changes is your IP address but according to me it should not matter as I have made my database public. So kindly explain what is this behaviour and how to fix this ?

Here is my azure portal:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQbrO.png)

And here is my java code in which I developed connection using mysql connector.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView tView;


    private  Connection connection = null;
    String url="jdbc:mysql://sda.mysql.database.azure.com:3306/helpgenic?useSSL=true&loginTimeout=30";



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tView = findViewById(R.id.textView);


        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);


        try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "azureuser", "Muhammad167");
            //connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            Toast.makeText(this,"Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e(String.valueOf(1), "Error occured here 1!");
            Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
}
```

I am totally stuck , getting no clue why this is happening.

Comment: Based on the first part of the question, I don't think this fits in Stack Overflow, and it would be more appropriate on another site.  It appears to be a question about Azure and/or network configuration.